# Pandas apply polyfit to a series against a value of the series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm new to the Pandas world and it has been hard to stop thinking sequentially.

I have a `Series` like:

```
df['sensor'].head(30)
0     6.8855
1     6.8855
2     6.8875
3     6.8885
4     6.8885
5     6.8895
6     6.8895
7     6.8895
8     6.8905
9     6.8905
10    6.8915
11    6.8925
12    6.8925
13    6.8925
14    6.8925
15    6.8925
16    6.8925
17    6.8925
Name: int_price, dtype: float64
```

I want to calculate the polynomial fit of the first value against all others to the find and average. I defined a function to do the calculation and I want it to be applied onto the series.

The function:

```py
def linear_trend(a,b):
    return np.polyfit([1,2],[a,b],1)
```

The application:

```py
a =  pd.Series(df_plot['sensor'].iloc[0] for x in range(len(df_plot.index))) 
df['ref'] = df_plot['sensor'].apply(lambda df_plot: linear_trend(a,df['sensor']))
```

This returns `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc lstsq_m`.

or this:

```
a =  df_plot['sensor'].iloc[0]
df['ref'] = df_plot['sensor'].apply(lambda df_plot: linear_trend(a,df['sensor']))
```

That returns `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you explain your desired output a bit more? I'm not clear on "calculate the polynomial fit of the first value against all others to the find and average."

Comment: I want to have the average slope of the lines the result of matching the first value with all the others of the Series, so, for X I will always have [1,2] and in : [5,1,2,3] I will calculate the slope (numpy.polyfit)  assuming [5, 1]  as Y ,then the same but instead of [5, 1] I will use [5, 2] and then [5, 3], finally I want to have the average of the result of each slope.
I hope I was clear enough ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work around my issue by doing the following:

```
a = pd.Series(data=(df_plot['sensor'].iloc[0] for x in range(len(df_plot.index))), name='sensor_ref')
df_poly = pd.concat([a,df_plot['sensor']],axis=1)
df_plot['slope'] = df_poly[['sensor_ref','sensor']].apply(lambda df_poly: linear_trend(df_poly['sensor_ref'],df_poly['sensor']), axis=1)
```

If you have a better method, it's welcome.